# Transform label font size

Tags: ios, swift, animation, label, transform

I have two shortcuts.
Each of them has initial properties, such as font size and opacity.
Before animation, the values ​​are

```
labelOne.font = labelOne.font.withSize(109)
labelOne.alpha = 1.0

labelTwo.font = labelTwo.font.withSize(40)
labelTwo.alpha = 0.7
```

After the animation, they should have these properties:

```
labelOne.font = labelOne.font.withSize(40)
labelOne.alpha = 0.7

labelTwo.font = labelTwo.font.withSize(109)
labelTwo.alpha = 1.0
```

For transformation, I use `CGAffineTransform()`
 example:

```
labelOne.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: //some value? , y: //someValue?)
```

But I'm new to programming and don't quite understand how it works. Tell me how to write this animation with font size resizing?

Comment: I did it a different way here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50876789/how-to-properly-morph-text-in-ios/50889550#50889550

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve an animation on both labels, as you wished by controlling font size and alpha, you could achieve it like this:

```
// Before animation
labelOne.font = labelOne.font.withSize(109)
labelOne.alpha = 1.0

labelTwo.font = labelTwo.font.withSize(40)
labelTwo.alpha = 0.7
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
    // This will be values set during the animation of 1 second
    self.labelOne.font = labelOne.font.withSize(40)
    self.labelOne.alpha = 0.7

    self.labelTwo.font = labelTwo.font.withSize(109)
    self.labelTwo.alpha = 1.0
})
```

Meanwhile, `CGAffineTransform(scaleX:, y:)` lets you scale the X,Y coordinates value of your view (labelOne for example), but to make that happen with an animation you have to put that inside the animate block:

```
// normal state
labelOne.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 1)
labelTwo.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.7, y: 0.7)
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
    // State reached through the animation
    labelOne.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.7, y: 0.7)
    labelTwo.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 1)
})
```

**To achieve a smoother transition play with:**

```
UIView.transition(with: labelOne, duration: 0.25, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
    self.labelOne.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 40)
}) { _ in }
```

Comment: it helped me but they decrease very sharply

Comment: You can reach the desired effect by playing with the duration value, alpha..

Comment: Maybe I need to resize UILabel along with the font?

Comment: Depends on the visual output you'd like to achieve

Comment: Well, I need to make UILabel shrink smoothly to the sizes I need, I think that I can change the font for this. But it decreases very sharply

Comment: Can you try with my last edit with `UIView.transition...`